# Rails f.select with a default value, but a different place holder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, form-helpers

I have this bit of code that produces a dropdown menu for me with a default value of Unassigned.

But, what I'd like to do is to have a placeholder, **Select Location**, on the dropdown menu, although by default the value selected is 'Unassigned'

Code:

```
= f.select :training_location_id, grouped_options_for_select(grouped_location_options, current_provider.locations.where(name: 'Unassigned').map { |loc| loc.id }), { placeholder: 'Select Location', include_blank: true }, class: 'form-control'
```

As you can see in the code, I'm setting a placeholder in the **f.select** { options }, but the dropdown menu still says "Unassigned"

Words of wisdom?

Answer (score 0):

try `include_blank: 'Select Location'`

```
= f.select :training_location_id, grouped_options_for_select(grouped_location_options, current_provider.locations.where(name: 'Unassigned').map { |loc| loc.id }), include_blank: 'Select Location' , class: 'form-control'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work...
Instances of 'Unassigned' are pulled from the DB, but I'd like to simply add a static placeholder that essentially prompts the user to select a location (yes, I've already tried the **prompt: '-- select location --'** with no effect)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this might work for you:

```
= f.select :training_location_id, grouped_options_for_select(grouped_location_options, current_provider.locations.where(name: 'Unassigned').map { |loc| loc.id }), data: { placeholder: 'Select Location' }, class: 'form-control'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work...
Instances of 'Unassigned' are pulled from the DB, but I'd like to simply add a static placeholder that essentially prompts the user to select a location (yes, I've already tried the **prompt: '-- select location --'** with no effect)

Answer (score 0):

1- Instead of using map to get selected option use find_by or where

```
 <%=f.select :training_location_id, grouped_options_for_select(grouped_location_options, current_provider.locations.where(name: 'Unassigned').first.id, {:prompt => '-- Select Location --'}),{class: 'form-control'}%>
```

Or

```
 <%=f.select :training_location_id, grouped_options_for_select(grouped_location_options, current_provider.locations.find_by(name: 'Unassigned').id, {:prompt => '-- Select Location --'}),{class: 'form-control'}%>
```

References: =

http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-grouped_options_for_select

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work...
Instances of 'Unassigned' are pulled from the DB, but I'd like to simply add a static placeholder that essentially prompts the user to select a location (yes, I've already tried the **prompt: '-- select location --'** with no effect)

I wish I could post a picture to show what I'm seeing on the front end!

Comment: @kdubss Please check the updated answer , as mentioned in doc  `prompt` will be used as placeholder. let me know for further guidance.

Comment: Just tested it out, now @Gabbar, and unfortunately...no dice.

Comment: @kdubss Not sure, why this is not working at your end, i have just tested it with following code sample:-
`<%grouped_options = {'North America' => [['United States','US'], 
'Canada'],'Europe' => ['Denmark','Germany','France']} %>`

`<%=f.select :training_location_id, grouped_options_for_select(grouped_options, nil, {:prompt => '-- Select Location --'}),{class: 'form-control'}%>`

And it's showing a option of `-- select location --`
you are missing something, can you try with this sample code.?

Comment: Hi @Gabber!

I will certainly try again!

The thing I really want is to display a placeholder prompting the user to make a selection, **but**, I want the **default value to be set to 'Unassigned'** just in case the user does not make a selection.  In this scenario, the people would be placed in the location 'Unassigned', whereas if the location was set to the placeholder string, the persons location assignment would be lost in limbo...